# Convert Shift_JIS format to UTF-8 format

Tags: java, android, utf-8, vcf-vcard, shift-jis

I am trying to convert a Shift_JIS formatted file into UTF-8 format. For this, below is my approach:

1. Read Shift_JIS file
2. getBytes of each line and convert it to UTF-8
3. Create new file and write UTF-8 converted value to it

Issue is that at step 2 conversion is not happening. I am using below code for converting Shift_JIS to UTF-8:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    byte[] b = line.getBytes("Shift_JIS");
    String value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

I have below 2 **questions**:

**1. Is there any other better way (steps) to do this conversion?**

**2. Why above code snippet is not working for conversion?**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer @VicJordan posted is not correct.  When you call `getBytes()`, you are getting the raw bytes of the string **encoded under your system's native character encoding** (which may or may not be UTF-8).  Then, you are treating those bytes as if they were encoded in UTF-8, which they might not be.

A more reliable approach would be to read the Shift_JIS file into a Java String.  Then, write out the Java String using UTF-8 encoding.

```
InputStream in = ...
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "Shift_JIS");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int read;
while ((read = reader.read()) != -1){
  sb.append((char)read);
}
reader.close();

String string = sb.toString();

OutputStream out = ...
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
writer.write(string);
writer.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It make sense

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. Was doing some very basic mistake. Below code is working perfectly fine:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "Shift_JIS"));
byte[] b = line.getBytes();
String value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy inFile (SHift_JIS) to outFile (UTF-8).

```
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile), "Shift_JIS");
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile), "UTF-8")) {
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    int size;
    while ((size = reader.read(buffer)) >= 0)
        writer.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
```