# Convert UTF-8 to Shift-JIS

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, shift-jis

I have written the simple conversion code to convert to Japanese character from UTF-8.

```
    private static String convertUTF8ToShiftJ(String uft8Strg) {
        String shftJStrg = null;
        try {

            byte[] b = uft8Strg.getBytes(UTF_8);
            shftJStrg = new String(b, Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS"));
            logger.info("Converted to the string :" + shftJStrg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return uft8Strg;
        }
        return shftJStrg;
    }
```

But it gives the output error,

```
convertUTF8ToShiftJ START !!
uft8Strg=*** abc000.sh é��å§�ã��ï¼�startedï¼�
*** abc000.sh å®�è¡�ä¸­ï¼�executing...ï¼�
*** abc000.sh çµ�äº�ã��ï¼�endedã��ï¼�*
```

Do anybody have any idea that where I made a mistake or need some additional logic, it would be really helpful!

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42136502/8349475

Comment: Check this one also. It is reverse of what you wanted i.e. Shift JIS to UTF-8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992097/convert-shift-jis-format-to-utf-8-format

Comment: You should never need to do this. When you have a string with wrong characters in it the problem happened when this string was first created or read. The fix must done at this place.

Answer (score 2):

You `String` is already a `String`, so your method is "wrong". UTF8 is an encoding that is a `byte[]` and can be converted to a `String` in Java.

It should read:

```
private static byte[] convertUTF8ToShiftJ(byte[] uft8) {
```

If you want to convert UTF8 `byte[]` to JIS `byte[]`:

```
private static byte[] convertUTF8ToShiftJ(byte[] uft8) {
    String s = new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return s.getBytes( Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS"));
}
```

A `String` can be converted to a `byte[]` later, by `mystring.getBytes(encoding)`

Please see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) for more detail.

Comment: thanks for your answer brother. Still having the problem so trying to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a conceptual misunderstanding about String encodings.
See for example [Byte Encodings and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html).

Converting a `String` from one encoding to another encoding doesn't make sense,
because `String` is a thing *independent* of encoding.

However, a `String` can be represented by byte arrays in various encodings
(like for example UTF-8 or Shift-JIS).
Therefore, it would make sense to convert a UTF-8 encoded *byte array*
to a Shift-JIS encoded *byte array*.

```
private static byte[] convertUTF8ToShiftJ(byte[] utf8Bytes) throws IllegalCharsetNameException  {
    String s = new String(utf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] shftJBytes = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS"));
    return shftJBytes;
}
```

Comment: Great answer :)

Comment: Actually, to be precise, `String`s also have an internal encoding (in memory). Nowadays that can be `LATIN1` and `UTF-16`. https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string. But then handing IO, best to always explicitly encode to bytes using a standard charset.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing out my conceptual misunderstanding. But still having the same issue. Now, trying to do some additional changes.